# Hierarchy C# component that loads each sub-"folder" only when clicked?

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, .net-4.5, treeviewitem

I am modifying [a Windows app](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/CmisSync/tree/master/SparkleShare/Windows) that uses `System.Windows.Control` UI elements,
I want to let the user select an item from a hierarchy, so something that looks like this:

[image: tree]

Except it is not folders, but a huge hierarchy of remote objects, very deep and slow to retrieve.
Loading the whole hierarchy before showing it would be too slow, I have to show the first level, and then show inside a folder when the user clicks on it.

I am thinking of using a `System.Windows.Control.TreeView` and intercept selection events on `TreeViewItem` elements to populate them when needed.
**QUESTION:** Is it the best practice strategy, or is there a `System.Windows.Control` UI element that is more appropriate for this?

A component that reads the content of each folder of the element clicked would be acceptable too.
The app uses `.NET 4.5`.

Comment: why not do a similar thing to the file browser dialog?  The pane is reused to show the contents of the selected hierarchy only, but you have an 'up' button to go back up (and as in Windows now, you can warp higher up the hierarchy by clicking on parts of the path in the explorer bar).

Comment: @AndrasZoltan: Yes, the file browser dialog would be great! Now the question is: Which component allows to reuse this dialog and just change the backend?

Comment: Well - there aren't any...  But it's something you can reproduce I should think.  Primarily it's just a dropdown and a listview (or the WPF equivalents).

Comment: You might be surprised how much a normal treeview can handle gracefully. Hundreds of thousands of items in just a few MB of RAM.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Happy to hear that! The server-side (where hierarchy information is pulled from) is, however, very slow. Letting alone any UI problem, just downloading all folders names recursively takes minutes, I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want child nodes to be loaded only when the parent node is expanded (e.g. by clicking its expand icon). Loading children upon node expansion indeed sounds better than loading them upon node selection, from a UX standpoint.

I'm not aware of anything that does that out of the box, but you can easily build one yourself. The approach I saw for this is to add a *dummy node* under each node whose children  haven't been fetched yet, and in the event handler for expanding a node, check if it has a dummy node, and if so load its actual child nodes and replace the dummy with them.

The dummy node causes its parent to appear to be expandable (e.g. have a '+' icon or collapsed triangle), which is probably what you need. If you put "(Loading...)" or some such as the title of the dummy, you'll get a decent user experience out of it.

Comment: +1 Your understanding is correct. I love the dummy node idea!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Additionally, to give the appearance of responsiveness, you might always want to download the next level or two down from the current node.  That way, your user isn't waiting when they open the nodes and it looks instantaneous.

Comment: @Avish Please do not ask for the user to accept your answers, it is an improper use of the commenting system.  Please don't do it again in the future.

Comment: @casperOne, that's new to me. I remember seeing such comments on other SX sites, usually helping new users understand how things work. Anyway, I won't do this again if it's frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create the TreeView:

```
System.Windows.Controls.TreeView treeView = new System.Windows.Controls.TreeView();
ContentCanvas.Children.Add(treeView);
```

2) Insert the root item(s):

```
System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem root = new System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem();
root.Header = repository;
treeView.Items.Add(root);
```

3) When one item is selected, add sub-item(s) as needed:

```
treeView.SelectedItemChanged += delegate
{
    TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)treeView.SelectedItem;
    SparkleLogger.LogInfo("bla", "object:"+item);
    System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem subItem = new System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem();
    subItem.Header = "hello";
    item.Items.Add(subItem);
};
```

Addition must be done at the first selection only, otherwise elements will be duplicated.
Any better solution would be warmly welcome!